# How to fetch data from database to textbox typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to fetch data from database to textbox typescript? My Get function is working it display on console but not on textbox.

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  Profile: Profile = new Profile; 
  
  constructor(
    private ProfileService: ProfileService,
    private Security: Security){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetProfileByID(this.Security.UserID);
  }
  
 GetProfileByID(UserID: any) {

  this.ProfileService.GetProfileByID(UserID).then(
    (response) => {
      console.table(response.Body)
    }
  )
  }
}
```

Here's my html

`

```
<form #updateForm="ngForm">
    <div class="input-container mb-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label>* Name</label>
            <input name="name" #name="ngModel" id="TACName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="Profile.Name" pInputText required/>
            <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div class="errortxt" [hidden]="!name.hasError('required')"> Name is Required!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="ui-button-raised submit-btn" [disabled]="!updateForm.valid || !Agreement" pButton label="SAVE" type="submit" (click)="Save(updateForm)"></button>
</form>
```

`

here's the result on console
[image]

Comment: Please add the result shown in console.

Comment: I added it already.

Comment: you are binding the value to `Profile` but you never assign any value to it. I believe that should be something like `this.Profile = response.Body;` (variables name anyway should always start in lower letter)

Comment: You're right. I thought I put it already. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According the output result in the console...

```
GetProfileByID(UserID: any) {

  this.ProfileService.GetProfileByID(UserID).then(
    (response) => {
      this.Profile.Name = response.Body.Name;
    }
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a typo, you should use `new Profile()` instead of `new Profile`.
2. Really recommending to not use [(ngModel)]. Use FormGroup instead and then after receiving your response from service, use `FormGroup.get(controlName: string).patchValue`. That will fix your issue for sure.